# Is "but" really a conjunction here?

Tags: parts-of-speech

*But* can be used to introduce an exclamation of surprise. Here's an example from Game of Thrones (not verbatim)

> But you're a pretty girl!

The sentence was supposed to mean roughly

> My god/Wow, you're a pretty....

The Oxford Dictionary does mention this *but* but they call it a conjunction. And that I find weird.

- What is this *but* conjoining?
- Isn't it a modal particle rather than a conjunction?

Comment: Why, you have such a nice question here!

Comment: If you want to call it a "conjunction", you can. If you want to call it something else, feel free. Names are not descriptions, and being called one thing or another does not convey any information, especially since no two people mean the same thing by "conjunction".

Comment: @JohnLawler... but I would think that there is a linguistic term "conjunction" for which there is a set of criteria that a word must meet in order to be categorized as such. I mean, I guess you'd agree that I can't call it a pronoun or a verb. Because it just doesn't do what those do. And at least in my eyes it doesn't do what a conjunction does.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say ***but*** in OP's example evokes contrast with an implicit [existential "it".](http://www.odlt.org/ballast/existential_it.html)

That's to say, ***but*** conjoins the exclamatory statement that follows with the *entire environment* of the speaker (before he noticed whatever "new thing" prompted him to make the exclamation).

Comment: Is there any linguistic backing for this explanation? I have an inkling that this "but" just doesn't fit the English 5 parts of speech system and while I respect the answer, I have to say that it is rather contrived from a scientific point of view :)

Comment: @Emanuel: OED defn 25: ***Introducing a statement** of the nature of an exception, objection, limitation, or contrast to what has gone before; **sometimes, in its weakest form**, merely expressing disconnexion, or **emphasizing the introduction of a distinct or independent fact***. I'd say the usage is dated/archaic anyway - but you asked *what* it conjoins, and I don't see any other possibility. I think "parts of speech" are pointless in this context, but note OED's defn 27: *expressing some degree of opposition ... also **colloquially, mere surprise or recognition of something unexpected**.*